# Rails ID error with Collection Check Boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox

I am working on a form to create a location (id, city, country_id) where the user enters the name of the city and then selects a country (id, name) from the following check boxes (collection_check_boxes).

I am using `forms_for` and passing an object from my LocationsController,

```
def new
    @location = Location.new
end 

   
#=>locations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
    
    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
    
    <br>
    <%= f.label :country %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :location, :country_ids, Country.all, :id, :name %>
    
    <br>
    <%= f.submit 'Create New Location' %>
<% end %>
```

I get `"location"=>{"city"=>"Denver", "country_id"=>["", "3"]}` in my params when I submit the form and I get this error `{:action=>"show", :controller=>"locations", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`

The following is my create and secure params methods::

```
def create
   redirect_to location_path(Location.create(location_params))
end

private

def location_params
   params.require(:location).permit(:city, country_ids: [])
end
```

I want to be able to **only** allow one check box for the country because a location shouldn't have more than one country (`city: 'Denver, country_id: ['1', '3']`) and create a new location with the selected country.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**locations/new.html.erb**

```rb
<%= f.label :country_id %>
<%= f.check_box :country_id, Country.pluck(:id, :name) %>
```

**locations_controller.rb**

```rb
def location_params
   params.require(:location).permit(:city, :country_id)
end
```

In form in views you tells that parameter is in :location hash by using `f.` helper. As long as you wrote `form_for @location` all results of the form will arrive to server inside of :location hash.

In controller you expect array in :country_ids parameter, but as long as you want to send only one id, you have to change it.

Comment: <%= f.collection_check_boxes :country_ids, Country.all, :id, :name do |c| %>
    <%= f.label :country_id %>
    <%= f.check_box :country_id, Country.pluck(:id, :name) %>
 <% end %> The error I get is: "no implicit conversion of Array into Hash"

Comment: try to copypast my code. You should not include one tag to another, as you did (according your comment). You don't need :collection_check_boxes tag there at all